# One Way to Grab both text and percentages regex python distinguish numbers from letters within parantheses

Tags: python, regex

I have this:

```
Bbc World News (57%); DANONE SA (FRANCE) (52%), Mn-Public-Radio-Intl; SIC123 Industry (52%)
```

I'd like to get:

```
[BBC World News, 57], [DANONE SA (FRANCE), 52], [Mn-Public-Radio Intl, 0], [SIC123 Industry, 52]
```

With the following helpfully suggested by Martijn Pieters, i can get everything besides DANONE SA (FRANCE). I'm not sure how to distinguish between (FRANCE) and (52%).

```
pat = r'(?(\b[\w\s\d!////&,:.%#@$-]+\b)(?:\s+\((\d+)%\))?'
[(name, int(perc) if perc else np.nan)
 for name, perc in re.findall(pat, inputtext)]
```

Comment: You're making it harder and harder to use regular expressions here; are digits part of the names, ever?

Comment: yes digits are sometimes part of the names

Comment: If you split the string first it may be easier, `re.split(",|;",s)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the `()` characters in the character class, but then it'll match the first characters of the percentage text (so `(57` in the case of `Bbc World News (57%)`. To make this all work still, you need to do a look-ahead to match on the trailing `,` or `;` or the end of the string:

```
re.findall(r'(\b[\w() -]+)(?:\s+\((\d+)%\))?(?=[,;]|$)', inputtext)
```

The `(?=...)` is a look-ahead match; that section is now anchored to any location that is followed either by a character matching the `[,;]` class or the end of a line. That makes the part before it, matching an optional `(..%)` percentage amount, only work before a comma or semicolon or the end of the text, and that then limits what the part before can match.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> import numpy as np
>>> inputtext = 'Bbc World News (57%); DANONE SA (FRANCE) (52%), Mn-Public-Radio-Intl; SIC123 Industry (52%)'
>>> [(name, int(perc) if perc else np.nan)
...  for name, perc in re.findall(r'(\b[\w() -]+)(?:\s+\((\d+)%\))?(?=[,;]|$)', inputtext)]
[('Bbc World News', 57), ('DANONE SA (FRANCE)', 52), ('Mn-Public-Radio-Intl', nan), ('SIC123 Industry', 52)]
```

Comment: this is really great! YOU ARE AMAZING! it appears to be working, but i need to try more cases. What harmful effects could happen you think if I added a space to (?=[,; ]|$).

Comment: @user3314418: try it out but that may well break the anchoring as it may match too many places.

Comment: @user3314418: `|` means *or*; match `[,;]` *or* match `$`. `$` matches the end of the string.